# Show error on pressing back/forward button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a login page,when the logged in user presses the back button ,the page should show error rather than showing login page and same should be applied on the forward button.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about which type of error occurs

Comment: i have created a login page and i want to to make a simple thing ,if a user sign in and then presses back button he should not be redirected to the login page but to be delivered with an error.

Comment: Which error? Error also have name  and type right?

Answer (score 0):

`window.onbeforeunload` event will fire when the user leaves the page.

```
var prevURL = document.referrer;

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(prevURL == 'provide your login page URL here') {
    return "Error message";  // alert
    //or do whatever you want
  }
};
```

Note that this event will fire when the user leaves the page for anyway.